# Forming an array with aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a document in MongoDB 3.4 with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3419e468d01013eadb83dc"),
    "id_station" : "62",
    "fiware_service" : null,
    "fiware_servicepath" : null,
    "id_fiware_name" : "CE_del_medio",
    "attrName" : "15",
    "attrType" : "float",
    "attrValue" : 0.33,
    "id_sensor_station_absolute" : "15_62",
    "recvTimeTs" : 1580387045,
    "recvTime" : "2020-01-30T12:24:05.00Z",
    "id_fiware" : "15",
    "sensor_type" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "id",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "15"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "img",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "assets/img/contrast.png"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "manufacturer",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "Hortisis"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "medida",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "mS/cm"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "name_comun",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "CE del medio"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "place",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "interior"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "timestamp",
            "type" : "DateTime",
            "value" : "2020-01-30T12:24:05.00Z"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "type",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "fertigation"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to convert the sensor_type field to an array with only one object, as follows:

```
{
   "_id":"15_62",
   "medidas":[
      {
         "_id":"5e3419e468d01013eadb83dc",
         "marca":"Hortisis",
         "modelo":"Estacion",
         "fabricante":"Hortisis",
         "id_station":"15",
         "sensor_type":[
            {
               "name":"15",
               "type":"fertigation",
               "place":"interior",
               "img":"assets/img/contrast.png",
               "name_comun":"Temp. Suelo",
               "medida":"mS/cm"
            }
         ],
         "attrName":"15",
         "attrValue":0.33,
         "recvTimeTs":1580387045,
         "recvTime":"2020-01-30T12:24:05.00Z",
         "id_sensor_station_absolute":"15_62"
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can really see it is formatting the sensor_type field = name : value.

I'm working with NODEJS and mongoose.

This is my query: (first I search, sort, only show the first value and then with the project I give format, the problem is that I don't know how to tell the project to put that format if I put "sensor_type": "$latest.attributes.name") it only shows the names and I don't know how to put it in the mentioned format.

```
Datagreenhouse.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "id_sensor_station_absolute": { "$in": array3 } } }, // "id_station": { "$in": id_station },
        { "$sort": { "recvTime": -1 } },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$id_sensor_station_absolute",
                "latest": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 1,
                "id_station": "$latest.id_station",
                //"id_sensor_station_absolute": "$id_sensor_station_absolute",
                "attrName": "$latest.attrName",
                "attrValue": "$latest.attrValue",
                "recvTimeTs": "$latest.recvTimeTs",
                "recvTime": "$latest.recvTime",
                "id_sensor_station_absolute": "$latest.id_sensor_station_absolute",
                "sensor_type": "$latest.attributes",


"name": { $arrayElemAt: ["$latest.attributes", 0] },
                "type": { $arrayElemAt: ["$latest.attributes", 1] },
                "place": { $arrayElemAt: ["$latest.attributes", 2] },
                "img": { $arrayElemAt: ["$latest.attributes", 1] },
                "name_comun": { $arrayElemAt: ["$latest.attributes", 4] },
                "medida": { $arrayElemAt: ["$latest.attributes", 3] },
                "interfaz": { $arrayElemAt: ["$latest.attributes", 6] },

            }
        }
    ], (err, DatagreenhouseRecuperado) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al realizar la peticion' + err })
        if (!DatagreenhouseRecuperado) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Error el usuario no existe' })
        res.status(200).send({ DatagreenhouseRecuperado })
    })
```

Thank you for your help. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 3.4.4, MongoDB introduced a magnific operator: [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html)

This operator allows us transmute array `key:value` pair into object.

### Syntax

```
RAW DATA                           $map                        $arrayToObject
sensor_type : [                    sensor_type : [             sensor_type : {
  {                             \    {                      \   
    "name" : "manufacturer", ---->     k: "manufacturer", --->   
    "type" : "String",          /      v: "Hortisis"        /    "manufacturer" : "Hortisis"
    "value" : "Hortisis"                    
  }                                  }
]                                  ]                            }
```

---

```
db.datagreenhouses.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {} // setup your match criteria
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "recvTime": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id_sensor_station_absolute",
      medidas: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          "marca": "Hortisis", // don't know where you get this value
          "modelo": "Estacion", // don't know where you get this value
          "id_station": "$id_station",
          "attrName": "$attrName",
          "attrValue": "$attrValue",
          "recvTimeTs": "$recvTimeTs",
          "recvTime": "$recvTime",
          "id_sensor_station_absolute": "$id_sensor_station_absolute",
          "sensor_type": {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: "$sensor_type",
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.name",
                  v: "$$this.value"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e2jFtGuGm2G)

---

```
[
  {
    "_id": "15_62",
    "medidas": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e3419e468d01013eadb83dc"),
        "attrName": "15",
        "attrValue": 0.33,
        "id_sensor_station_absolute": "15_62",
        "id_station": "62",
        "marca": "Hortisis",
        "modelo": "Estacion",
        "recvTime": "2020-01-30T12:24:05.00Z",
        "recvTimeTs": 1.580387045e+09,
        "sensor_type": {
          "id": "15",
          "img": "assets/img/contrast.png",
          "manufacturer": "Hortisis",
          "medida": "mS/cm",
          "name_comun": "CE del medio",
          "place": "interior",
          "timestamp": "2020-01-30T12:24:05.00Z",
          "type": "fertigation"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

All you need to do is transform data to the desired result with an easy to handle object (`$unwind` medidas field, transform and then `$group` again)

**Note:** If your MongoDB is earlier 3.4.4 version, follow update procedure:

1. Install MongoDB 3.4.4 or newer
2. Make `mongodump` with new version MongoBD
3. Stop old MongoBD
4. Remove /data directory (make backup)
5. Start new MongoDB and run `mongorestore`

Comment: First of all thanks for the help. a doubt: if this collection has more records of the same sensor but only changes the date and value how can I have the last value inserted? before to "latest": {"$ first": "$$ ROOT"}, but it takes a lot and in this case it would not work and limit is not valid since the input parameters are an array and only shows one element and would have to Be the last of each.

Comment: @Manolait change `$push` to `$first` / `$last`

Comment: if I change $push for $first it gives me "sensor_type": null

Comment: @Manolait can you share more samples to try to reproduce your case, because `$first` should work perfecto. Make sure field name written correctly

Comment: I add the tests with the error: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gIrdnsSpWpy

Comment: @Manolait As i said, field name changed. Now it calls `attributes` Check it https://mongoplayground.net/p/JsQvcV_jhwe

Comment: You were right. I'm sorry for the mix-up. Thank you so much for helping me with this. Greetings.